# How to make a permanent change to an element after using jQuery's .keydown()?

Tags: jquery, keydown

I have the following jQuery code:

```
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length == 0)
{
    $('#mySearch').html('');
    return;
}
else
{
    $('#mySearch').load('search/'+str,function(){
        $('#mySearch').css({
            'background-color': 'white',
            'width': '250px',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'right': '0'
        })
    });
}

$(document).click(function(event) {
if ( !$(event.target).hasClass('mySearch'))
{
     $('#mySearch').html('');
     $('#main_search').val('');
}
});

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
       $('#mySearch tr.myRow:first').addClass("a_classy_class");
       return false;
    }
});
}
```

When I press the down arrow key the class 'a_classy_class' is added to the tag with id 'myRow'. However, as soon as I stop pressing the down arrow key the class is removed. How do I make the change permanent, so that after I stop pressing the down arrow key the change holds?

Comment: *"When I press the down arrow key the class 'a_classy_class' is added to the tag with id 'myRow'. However, as soon as I stop pressing the down arrow key the class is removed."* That doesn't make any sense. Once a class is added, it will not be removed unless you remove it (or you completely replace the element with another one that's essentially the same but without the class).

Comment: To add to what T.J. said, the class will not be removed unless some other code removes it.  So, somewhere else you must have code (that you haven't disclosed here) that is causing this issue.  There's not much we can do until you find/disclose that other code.

Comment: I just added the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other suggestions, if the page is reloaded, your changes will not persist.

Answer (score 0):

Something else in your code is removing the class, or replacing the row with one that doesn't have it. Absent that, there's nothing that will magically remove the class from the row. [Proof](http://jsbin.com/odadur)

Your `#anID tr#myRow:first` selector suggests that you may have issues with your HTML. An ID selector always selects a unique element, because `id` values **must** be unique on the page. So there's no need for the `:first` part of `#myRow:first`. So perhaps that has something to do with it, but I'm guessing at this point.

Comment: Thanks. I changed #myRow to a class. It still doesn't work though. As soon as I stop pressing the down arrow key the class is removed.