# JQuery keydown event changes removed when letting go of key

Tags: jquery, events, time, keydown, short

I am trying to create an auto-suggest box. When a user starts typing in the #tagSelection input field, JQuery fetches suggestions from the database through Ajax and display these in the #suggestBox div that is displayed right under the #tagSelection field.

Now I want to enable the user to use the arrow down key to select one of the suggestions. I have started building this by handling the keydown() event and assigning a class to the first entry during this event. The problem I am facing is that the class is removed again when I let go of the arrow down key. I need it to stay assigned when I let go of the key. Is that possible?

The HTML

```
<div class="form-entry">
    <input id="tagSelection" name="tags" type="text" value="" size="40">

    <div id="suggestBox" style="">
        <a href="#" id="1">design</a>
        <a href="#" id="3">debit card</a>
        <a href="#" id="4">deer</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="#" id="addTag">Add word</a>

    <div id="selectedTags"></div>

</div>
```

The JQuery

```
(function() {
    $('#tagSelection').keydown(downArrowKeyHandler);
})();

function downArrowKeyHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        if ($('#suggestBox').length > 0) {
            if ($('[tagSelected = 1]').length == 0) {
                // the tagSelected class gives the entry a colored background
                $('#suggestBox').children().filter(':first').addClass('tagSelected');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 40 is down key ascii code?

Comment: What's `'[tagSelected = 1]'`? Do you mean `'.tagSelected'`? (Or maybe you're using a technique I don't know about.) The above code doesn't look like it can possibly remove classes; check elsewhere for other event-handling hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact same problem here:

[How to make a permanent change to an element after using jQuery's .keydown()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648683/how-to-make-a-permanent-change-to-an-element-after-using-jquerys-keydown?rq=1)

It seems I indeed had some other JQuery code that was interfering with my event handler. Whenever someone releases a key when in the #tagSelection field a JQuery method fires that retrieves the suggestions from the db. The already present keyup() event was interfering with my new keydown() event.

```
(function() {
    $('#tagSelection').keyup(tagboxTypingHandler)
})();


function tagboxTypingHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode != 40) {
        var substring = $('#tagSelection').val();
        if (substring.length > 1) {
            $.get("http://localhost:8080/tag/search/" + substring, returnedTagsHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

I just added the event.keyCode != 40 condition and now the class remains on the suggestion and it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correct, Jquery autocomplete is enough in this case. try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rdworth/AgpaN/)

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tags">
</div>

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl" ],
    delay: 0
});
```

Comment: I'd prefer an answer to this particular question. I need too much custom behaviour to go with a third party plugin and I want to learn this stuff myself.

Comment: autocomplete is just a jquery stuff. which you already using.

Answer (score 1):

**JS CODE:**

```
$("input").keypress( function() {
var s = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
other params
success: function(data) { // here data contains all the suggest echoed with comma seprated (see below)
var s = data.split(",");
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: s,
    delay: 0
});
});
});
```

**In PHP It should be echoed like this**

```
siren,sam,sami,salman
```

Comment: well you gonna also disrespect me? i have the same answer?